# logging 2 web apps to 2 different files

Tags: log4j, tomcat6

I have 2 web applications built from the same source tree within tomcat, which each use a PropertyConfigurator loading their respective `/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties`.

Currently tomcat is configured to use one console appender for the whole container, and both app's log4js just write to the console:

```
log4j.rootCategory=info, A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
```

This means I end up with one big `catalina.out` for the whole container.

I would like to configure each of the applications log4js so that they append to their own separate rolling files.

I'm aware I can use system properties substitution within `log4j.properties` however isn't system properties shared across the VM and therefore not threadsafe between the 2 applications within the container?

Can someone suggest a tidy solution which allows me to configure the 2 applications to log to separate files, preferably with the application's context name within the log's file name.

thanks, p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your log4j.jar and commons-logging.jar placed in tomcat directory? And which version of tomcat you are using?

If you have one copy of these jar inside common/lib than surely catalina.log would be used by all logging since tomcat's log4j.properties file is only the one getting configured for both server and webapps under it.

Assuming this scenario holds valid in your case, copy log4j.jar and common-logging.jar under WEB-INF/lib for both web applications.

For using application name within log's file name, since separate log4j.properties file is used for each application, name your logfiles as you like in log4j.properties file against FileAppender or RollingFileAppender.